# Can't insert rows into sqlite database using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

For some reason, the following code is not storing any data in my sqlite database.  The return code is SQLITE_DONE (101) so it is not giving me any error messages.  The method is being called a number of times to populate a few rows in the database.  Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

```
- (void)storePersonInDatabase:(Person *)person {
    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, NOTES, ADDRESS, PROMOTED, VEGETARIAN) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    // Prepare the data to bind.
    NSData *imageData = person.imageData;
    NSString *personId = [person.personId stringValue];
    NSString *personName = person.name;
    NSString *address = person.address;
    NSString *notes = person.notes;
    NSString *isVegetarian = (person.isVegetarian) ? @"1" : @"0";
    NSString *isPromoted = (person.isPromoted) ? @"1" : @"0";

    // Prepare the statement.
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Bind the parameters (note that these use a 1-based index, not 0).
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [personId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [personName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [notes UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [address UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [isPromoted UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [isVegetarian UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    }

    // Execute the statement.
    int returnCode = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (returnCode != SQLITE_DONE) {
        // error handling...
        NSLog(@"An error occoured");
    }
```

//This is how I set up the db

```
NSString *sqliteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Persons" ofType:@"sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([sqliteDb UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Unable to open database");
}
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: Instead of binding Data to SQ query pass data directly to Inser query ...

Comment: Where is you SQLite data files stored?

Comment: I will also need to store an image in this row so I was trying to avoid putting the strings directly in the query. The SQLite data file is stored in the root directory of the project. I am able to read from it no problem.

Comment: are you getting inserted value in SELECT query ?

Comment: No, I manually added some values in the command line and am able to read those.

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, SQLite is all new to me!

Comment: is the database in the appbundle or allready copied to the document directory?

Comment: Please use this to print error msg NSLog(@"%s: step error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db)); in else

Comment: Yes its in the app bundle, along with my other class files.

Comment: umm, 1. the way to check for errors in sqlite is to use `sqlite3_errcode` after each call, 2. anything in app bundle is read-only. so you need to copy the sqlite file to Documents directory before doing any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you show how you try to open a sqlite file in your app bundle

**you cant write to your app bundle**

**the app bundle is read only**

you need to copy it somewhere you can write to. It sounds like it should go to library/documents.

the pseudo code is:

```
if(!sqlite_already_in_library) {
    [file_manager copyFileFrom:sqlite-in-bundle to:sqlite-in-library_path];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a few people have suggested, you need to copy the database to a location outside of your project bundle. There you can read and write as you wish, otherwise you are essentially just creating new databases every time you try to run your 'storePersonInDatabase' method.

You should perform that same check that Daij-Djan provided before trying to interact with your database. You should also save the location or name of your database somewhere for easy access and file checking.